# How to get DHCP from other bands of DHCP server without DHCP relay package

Tags: linux, dhcp, network-topology

[image: topology]

This is the topology that I want to make of.
User gets DHCP from `ex-ns`, but can't use any packages on router such as `isc-dhcp-relay`, `dnsmasq`, `dhcp-help`, etc. I think it should use things like `iptables` or bridge interfaces.